# Is there a rental agency for Citroen 2CVs, Meharis or Renault R4s in Corsica?

Tags: car-rentals, nostalgia, corsica

Going to Corsica, I'd prefer renting a fun classic french car like those listed in the title to a modern one. However, I could only find rental agencies for those classics in continental France.

Are there any trustworthy "youngtimer" agencies on Corsica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe too late for you...

I found three cars in Corsica on that site: [Locations Rétro Mariage](https://www.lrm-collection.fr/Location-voiture-mariage,Corse,page-1,20,0.htm).

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed too late but good to know. During my stay in Corsica, I did not find any other options.